# Input type file not uploading file with name as test (copy).csv

Tags: php, html, forms, csv, input

I have created an import / export (CSV) application in PHP PDO and MySQL.
Everything is working.
but when i try to import the file with the filename as FILENAME (copy).csv it is not getting upload. i think form is not getting submit only. and if i import the file with the filename as FILENAME.csv it is working fine.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="import.php" method="post" name="frmCSVImport" id="frmCSVImport" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="input-row">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="import" class="btn-submit btn btn-primary" value="Import">
     </div>
</form>
```

PHP(import.php):

```
if (isset($_POST["import"])) {

$fileName = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

    $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
    $flag = true;

    while (($column = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        if($flag) { $flag = false; continue; }

        $requiredHeaders = array('Name', 'Email', 'Event_name'); //headers we expect

        $f = fopen($fileName, 'r');
        $firstLine = fgets($f); //get first line of csv file
        fclose($f);

        $foundHeaders = str_getcsv(trim($firstLine), ',', '"'); //parse to array

        if ($foundHeaders !== $requiredHeaders) {
        echo 'Headers do not match: '.implode(', ', $foundHeaders);
        die();
        }else
        {


            echo $name = $column[0]."<br>";
            echo $email = $column[1]."<br>";
            echo $event_name = $column[2]."<br>";

        }
    }
}
```

}

i don't know why this is happening. can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: Does the file already exist on the server and thus doesn't get uploaded? Do other files with a space in their name get uploaded correctly? We'd need the code for upload handling to help any further.

Comment: @kerbholz Yes.other files with a space in their name is getting uploaded correctly. i have added the PHP code in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, there was this below script for validating the csv filename.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frmCSVImport").on("submit", function () {

        $("#response").attr("class", "");
        $("#response").html("");
        var fileType = ".csv";
        var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + fileType + ")$");
        if (!regex.test($("#file").val().toLowerCase())) {
                $("#response").addClass("error");
                $("#response").addClass("display-block");
            $("#response").html("Invalid File. Upload : <b>" + fileType + "</b> Files.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

});
</script>
```

i removed that code and it started working. obviously. :D
Sorry guys. my bad.